# How to optimize my distributed application's queueing and buffering of network messages for performance?

Tags: c++, network-programming

In most cases application needs to use a few machines in order to perform on the required scale. The main application (master) connects to other machines and executes the worker processes. The machines are expected to be connected to a network, but the physical connection might be through pure ethernet and might be separate and go over the internet.
During the execution many messages are sent between the master and each worker process. The problem is that many different parts of our code are allowed to send messages and also customized user code can. It is impossible to predict the messages timing size and frequency. The user is expected to connect a strong enough network for his needs, but we're trying to optimize performance as much as possible.

All parts of the application would use the same communication module API to send the messages.

My question:
Are there network/internet performance issues with sending too many separate small messages frequently?
In this case, does my communication module need to collect bunches of messages together and send them in single bigger ones?
Does it need to break huge messages to smaller ones?
What are the exact frequency and sizes that could cause performance problems (I mean network/internet performance)?
Or does the OS/hardware do all this automatically for me?
If the module has to do it, are there any c++ libraries that could help me with that? (preferably open source allowed for commercial use)
Collecting messages as such will ofcourse cause most messages not to be sent immediately when the process asks but a bit later. I can require any code in my application that sends a message to specify how much the message can be delayed (without disruptng his requirements). Most messages wouldn't mind being delayed even a few seconds.

Apparently I don't have much background in network implementations, but I know I should clarify that with the API I expect to use, I need every message to succeed. If it fails I just stop the application and notify the user. There is no recovery possible.

Comment: Is your program communicating over TCP?  UDP?  Something else?

Comment: Have you considered using Latency Busters Messaging (LBM)?

Comment: @Jeremy Friesner - I'm supposed to redesign the communication module, so I'm trying to figure what I can use to do that. Latency is not a big issue for me, most my messages have to reach within a few seconds. The problem might be the big amount of the messages. In any case I will base on a module that guarantees that messages would reach destination, I won't use UDP directly.

Comment: @sonicoder - I don't know about that no. I don't know much about any interprocess/network communication. I program c++ for quite a few years, but I only ever used the interprocess communication modules, never had to design or change them.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.  In general, there is more overhead at the network layers when sending many smaller messages versus fewer larger ones.  Latency also exacerbates the overhead of smaller datagrams because of windowing; this is more of an issue in a WAN environment.

You should do some small scale testing in your specific environment since there are many variables and we'd need much more detail of the network environment even to give just estimates.

Comment: As many different users would use the application on different networks, I cannot give a single environment description. I can make the application configurable with the optimum message size/frequency for each environment. But my question is mainly whether at all my communication module needs to do that, or does the hardware/OS does it for me?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there will be overhead associated with sending a lot of small messages frequently, and it's up to the application to implement a good bandwidth utilisation solution.

There are no hard and fast rules regarding how to best utilise your network traffic, it's largely application dependent. In game development we tend to have a lot of small packets sent frequently, so we try to append these onto a packet up to our maximum payload size and then send that. This ensures we have good bandwidth utilisation.

What is the maximum payload size? A good rule of thumb is to take the network MTU and subtract the protocol headers, as well as any overhead you need for reassembly. These are variables specific to your environment.

There is a trade off here though - you can't wait forever to fill up to your max payload size so the buffer must be flushed within a time period reasonable for your application's performance, and the perception of latency by the user.

Comment: Great. So what exactly is the API that every message sender uses? He needs to specify the maximum time he allows the message to be delayed?
Did you implement the module yourself or you got suggestion for published modules (c++)?

Comment: It depends on the platform. Some platform SDKs provide the functionality, others don't. A good open source library for game development is enet (http://enet.bespin.org/) but this provides far more than you probably need, such as a reliable UDP implementation. It's also very much geared towards game development. I'm sure there are plenty of other libraries out there, but rolling your own API using sockets is really not that difficult.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a *messaging bus*. Firstly any metrics you will find on this type of setup (messaging bus), should be taken with a pinch of salt - you need to take a particular solution and test it first to get an idea of what your particular environment is capable of.

As for OS products that will give you a message bus out of the box, here are a few:

1. ZeroMQ
2. AMQP (Red Hat have an implementation)

Both above are MQ based.

1. OpenDDS (this is a more solid implementation)

The advantage of the above are that they provide the whole bus, and your application simply produces and consumes "messages". You don't have to worry about any of the low-level stuff (serialization, "queueing", "routing" etc.) until you need to tune (TCP/UDP etc.) As for small packets vs. large etc. I think that depends entirely on your requirements - can you handle the delay or does it have to be low latency etc. There's no hard and fast answers to any of this stuff, it's all in experimentation...

If you want to roll your own, consider a mix of boost::asio, google protocol buffers and then your own "routing" and pub/sub abstractions - in another words, test one of the OS products above - it's pretty tricky to RYO.. ;)

There are of course commercial products and costs can vary from tens of thousands of dollars to millions.. :)

Comment: Thanks. I checked OpenDDS. It seems that DDS QoS option LATENCY_BUDGET is defined to do what I was looking for. That is hint that the message doesn't have to be send ASAP but can be delayed some time in order to improve efficiency (by packing more messages). But their developer guide at 3.2.15 states that this option isn't implemented, can you suggest anything about that? As for OS, I cannot choose, currently I have to run on windows and some versions of linux, but OS is basically the user's choice.